# Get list of filenames in assets folder with Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript1.8

How do I get all filenames in a folder using Typescript?
It's for an angular 2 project.

To be more specific, what I'm trying to do is set the images for a bootstrap carousel using images from my photos folder. Currently I'm doing this:

```
private _images: Image[] = []

ngOnInit(): void {
    this._images = [
        { "title": "Slide 1", "url": "../photos/carousel/gg_slide 1.jpg" },
        { "title": "Slide 2", "url": "../photos/carousel/gg_slide 2.jpg" },
        { "title": "Slide 3", "url": "../photos/carousel/gg_slide 3.jpg" },
        { "title": "Slide 4", "url": "../photos/carousel/gg_slide 4.jpg" },
        { "title": "Slide 5", "url": "../photos/carousel/gg_slide 5.jpg" }
    ]
}//ngOnInit
```

Then using the the images array in the html file like this:

```
<carousel>
    <slide *ngFor="let img of _images">
        <img src="{{img.url}}" alt="{{img.title}}">
    </slide>
</carousel>
```

I'd like to be able to just loop through whatever files are in the photos folder and add them to the images array.
That way all I have to do to update the carousel is to change the photos in the photos folder.

Comment: There are no folders in the browser. Please be more specific about what you try to accomplish.

Comment: That depends on where you code is running (browser vs. server), and has nothing to do with Typescript.

Comment: I guess the OP is trying to build an UI where he can choose a file from local folders.

Comment: You need to customize your web server so that it provides an API that allows you to make a HTTP request and get the list of files in return (for example as array), then you can use a component like shown in your question to display it. Without special server support you're out of luck. The browser runs on the client, the directories are on the server, therefore the browser can't know about directories without getting the information from the server.

Comment: That makes sense. I don't think I really considered where the code was going to run.

Comment: I don't really know it it exists but there should be a *webpack loader* that scans specified folder and creates array of urls, statically at build time. This could be an alternative to creating API that returns such array each time a page is opened.

Comment: Ahead of time webpack compilation building a json or other format for all available files would be awesome. Not sure why this isn't a standard Angular feature.

Answer (score 3):

I have been unable to find a solution using Javascript. It appears that JS does not have the ability to read file structures. Instead you will have to keep a list on the backend in a database or create a json file that you keep up to date with all of the icons manually.

[I have found this example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54420869/1457219)

As accessing file from `assets` folder is easy, so we can exploit it
 and we can store an array of icon file names in the file say, `icons.json`.

**1.** Create `icons.json` as following in the `assets` folder-

```
{  // ---------- icons.json---------
  "icons-array" : ["icon-name1", "icon-name2", "icon-name3"]
}
```

**2.** Keep `icon-name1.svg`, `icon-name2.svg`, `icon-name3.svg` file in the `assets/icons` folder.

**3.** Read `icons-json` file at start-up of the angular application. 
      **[How to read file at Angular Application Start-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54176684/how-to-change-urls-automatically-in-services-after-changing-url-it-should-affec/54178616#54178616)**
**4.**   After reading `icons.json` content, store value of `icons-array` property into a global accessible array, say     `globalAccessibleIconsArray`.

 **5.**  And use the array as-

```
for (const icon of globalAccessibleIconsArray) {
      this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIconInNamespace(
        'my-namespace',
        icon,
        domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(`./assets/icons/${icon}.svg`)
      );
    }
```

So, for Adding a new icon

- you have to put the new icon file in the `assets/icon` folder, and
- add the new file name in the `icons.json` file present in the `assets` folder.

Comment: I think it should also be possible to generate this json automatically at build time / serve time as nodejs file management api should be available.

Answer (score 2):

The way I ended up solving a similar issue of wanting to read all the static blog post files from `src/assets/posts/` was that I incorporated reading these into a `posts.ts` file as a build step:

```
"scripts": {
     ...
    "pre-build": "echo 'export default [' > posts.ts; ls src/assets/posts/ | tac | awk '{ print \"\\\"\"$0\"\\\",\"}' >> posts.ts; echo ']' >> posts.ts;",
    "build": "npm run pre-build && ng build",
  },
```

And then in Angular I read from `posts.ts`:

```
import posts from "../../../posts"

@Component({
  selector: 'app-posts',
  templateUrl: './posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts.component.scss']
})
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {

  originalPosts = posts;
  
  // rest of the class
}
```

Also included my `posts.ts` file in `tsconfig.app.json`:

```
  ...
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "posts.ts"
  ],
  ...
```

---

To explain the `pre-build` command: it consists of 3 bash commands:

1. `echo 'export default [' > posts.ts;`: Clears the file and writes `export default [` to the posts.ts
2. `ls src/assets/posts/ | tac | awk '{ print "\""$0"\","}' >> posts.ts;` Lists all filenames in `src/assets/posts/`, reverse sorts them (with `tac`), surrounds them with quotes (with `awk`) and appends to `posts.ts`
3. `echo ']' >> posts.ts;` appends closing `]` to the file.

---

This solution is similar to the one in previous answer, but has the advantage of not hard-coding any values into json by hand (error-prone) and instead it is done automatically during build

Comment: Note: this requires running build scripts via `sh`-like console and having necessary tools installed in your system. Solution that implements the same functionality via just `npm` or `node` (e.g. using `fs.readdirSync`) would be less restricting.