# Angular: read all files from asset folder

Tags: angular, angular-material2

tltr: can I access the assets directory from angular?

I have a bunch of SVGs in a folder `src/assets/icons` that I use with `mat-icon`. The only drawback is when I add a new icon, I have to add the file and I have to add the filename to an array which I use to loop through for adding it to `matIconRegistry`. Is there a way to simply read all files from the directory?

Here's my current solution:

```
@NgModule()
export class CustomIconModule {
  constructor(
    private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
    private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {
    const icons = [
      'icon1', 'icon2',
    ];

    for (const icon of icons) {
      this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIconInNamespace(
        'my-namespace',
        icon,
        domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(`./assets/icons/${icon}.svg`)
      );
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATE: I wrote a bash script, that loops through the file, generates a .ts file with an array of all the filenames and does `git add`. I run it in the pre-commit git hook. not ideal, but it kinda works for now. I would love to find a pure JS solution, though.

Comment: Have a look at importing file-system so you can loop through the asset folder.

Comment: @masterfloda if reading file is okay, then please review my answer, and see if its that you wanted or i have to improve.

Comment: @masterfloda: Could you share your bash script as an answer? I have a similar problem right now trying to find all available language JSON files in my `assets/i18n` folder

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45221257/959484