# How to get all translations configured in Angular project by i18n?

Tags: angular, pipe, angular7, angular-i18n

I am using i18n (internationalization) in Angular 7 with the following languages: en, es, fr, it, pl, pt and ru.

I need to get all languages configured in the project for setting a drop-down list with their values. How can I get these languages, set in JSON files, to use them in the drop-down list?

Can I loop the files in the folder, at least, and recover the filenames?

Comment: You are trying to get the list of the translations in a dropdown list which then when perform for click will change to the selected language ?

Comment: @Spritzig Yes, I am trying it exactly. :).

Comment: I have till now created manually a list which I have added the translations but to get them I didn't try it, I will make a new project and will try to get that it will be a challenge for me to.

Comment: @Spritzig Amazing man... You are the best

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45221257/959484

Comment: @Samoth. Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access i18n folder to get file list in angular.

You need create API to read it. This way I implement in project, i share for whon concern.

```
[Route("api/webconfiguration/getlanguages")]
        [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
        public dynamic GetLanguages()
        {    
            string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LanguageFolder"];

            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.json");
            if (files.Length > 0)
            {
                var languages = files.Select(file => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name));
                return languages.Select(c => new { code = c, name = new CultureInfo(c).DisplayName }).ToList();
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Configure in web.config

```
<add key="LanguageFolder" value="C:\src\assets\i18n"/>
```

Create service to get language list and use in in component.

```
getLanguages() {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>('/api/webconfiguration/getlanguages').pipe(
      map(response => <any>response));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I can till now offer you to do it is something like this.
Till I achieve what you are looking for hope this will work.
This is only an example.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let language of languageList">
 <a href="/{{language.code}}/">
 <button class="button">{{language.label}}</button>
 </a>
</ng-container>
```

This is the list declared in the `.TS`

```
languageList = [
   { code: 'en', label: 'English' },
   { code: 'de', label: 'German' },
   { code: 'es', label: 'Espanol' }
];
```

Comment: Well, not exactly... I am looking for a code which recognize language translated in i18n automatically and post them in the html. After, you can choose the default language for being the language which translate the words use in the html. Thanks mate :)

Comment: I am trying to find a solution about you question.
I have a question.
Do you want to recognize the browser language ?

Comment: Really good question... Thanks for answering me Spritzig, sorry for not reply you before. Well, up to you. Will be amazing recognize all languages availables in i18n (for fill the combo) and recognize the browser language for setting it by default in the combo... That will be the best scenario... But just could work just if you get all languages only... 
Thanks mate.