# No array operations work on getLangs() from ngx-translate/core TranslateService

Tags: javascript, ngx-translate

I work on an Angular (v13) project which uses `ngx-translate/core` for i18n. There are multiple languages (15 currently) configured. I find the following **very strange** behaviour (TranslateService is injected as `this.translateService`):

1. Calling `this.translateService.getLangs()` returns an array with the 15 language codes as expected. I can log this value or e.g. configure a dropdown select with these values.
2. However, I can do absolutely no array operations on this value, including indexing `[0]` (says `undefined`), `.length` (returns 0), or `for-in` or `for-of`. No `...` operator to create a new array or object with the values, no `Object.assign([], langs)`, no `Array.from()` - they just return empty arrays. Let alone `.map()`, `.forEach()`, etc.
3. `typeof` says object, `Array.isArray()` says true.

Some basic example code:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(
      this.translateService.getLangs(),
      this.translateService.getLangs().length,
      this.translateService.getLangs()[0],
      this.translateService.getLangs().includes('en'),
      this.translateService.getLangs().includes('aa')
    );
}
```

shows in the console:

```
[] 0 undefined false false
```

and if I expand the `[]` it shows the 15 codes (including 'en'), and `length: 15`.

#### Questions

1. Am I reading the [ngx-translate documentation](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#methods) wrong (that what is there)?
2. Am I using it wrong somehow due to not understanding something?
3. Is this a bug in `ngx-translate`?
4. Is this a bug in JavaScript?
5. Is there any workaround?

Comment: It works as expected, but, it seems that you call the `getLangs()` function early before loading the langs. Try to move this to another component, or simply try to use `setTimeout` to know where the problem is exactly in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to [Amer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15159603/amer) for his comment pointing me in the right direction.

- The problem occurs because **`this.translateService.getLangs()` is called before languages have been loaded via `this.translateService.addLangs()`**. The language values are obtained via a [`HttpClient.get()`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get) request, which returns an [`Observable`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Observable) and calls `addLangs()` once the results are received (refer `Observable.subscribe(...)`). (So no funny happenings, just a wrong understanding.)
- The simple **solution** is to only do any operations on the array of languages in the `complete` callback of the `Observable` returned by `HttpClient.get()` (or use one of the other synchronization mechanisms available). This was a bug in the original code and has now been fixed.
- The browser (Chrome) logging `[]` (which could then be expanded to the full array) was a confusion on my part. When the array is available at logging time, it is logged as expanded, e.g. `[ "ar", "en", .... ]`. (By the time I clicked on the expansion widget in the console, the array had obviously been loaded in the mean time, which enables it to be shown on expansion.)
- I strongly advise against synchronization via timeouts as someone may wrongly read from Amer's comment, where it is suggested only for problem detection. One should always use one of the synchronization methods (Promises, Observables,  events, etc. etc.) in final code to synchronize between asynchronous processes.

Comment: Which function of this plugin do you use as an Observable, because **getLangs()** does not seem to be observable ?

Comment: @BenjaminLemoine The `Observable` thing is explained in the first 2 points, can you re-read and see if it answers you concern? I added slight edits for clarity.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45221257/959484

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this exact same issue by holding it in a field which is only initialized later.

```
protected availableLanguages: string[] = [];

constructor(protected translateService: TranslateService)
{
  this.translateService.store.onLangChange.pipe(takeUntilDestroyed()).subscribe((_: LangChangeEvent): void => {
    this.availableLanguages = this.translateService.store.langs;
    this.availableLanguages.sort();
  });
}
```

It can be tested e.g. in jasmine like this, the key is to recreate the component for the constructor to be called again after the overwrite of the event emitter:

```
it('should handle default language change', () =>
{
  const eventEmitter: EventEmitter<LangChangeEvent> = new EventEmitter<LangChangeEvent>();
  component['translateService'].store.onLangChange = eventEmitter;
  component['translateService'].store.langs = ['de', 'en'];

  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;

  expect(component['availableLanguages']).toEqual(arrayContaining([]));

  eventEmitter.emit({
    lang: 'de',
    translations: {}
  });

  expect(component['availableLanguages']).toEqual(arrayContaining(['de', 'en']));
});
```